# A part of WCF service URL is generating dynamically each time

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis

I am a complete new in WCF serivce. 
I have developed this REST WCF service(a routing service).

my web.config

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>

<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <standardEndpoints>
        <webHttpEndpoint>
            <!-- 
        Configure the WCF REST service base address via the global.asax.cs file and the default endpoint 
        via the attributes on the <standardEndpoint> element below
    -->
            <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"/>
        </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>

    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" policyVersion="Policy12"/>

            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>

    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

And after publishing it to IIS I am getting url like this:

http://xxxx.com:8001/ACT/(S(2wpucy0oasurckuompimgqdo))/GetUser

Each time the token like segment (S(2wpucy0oasurckuompimgqdo)) gets dynamically generated if I publish it to IIS.

I don't know where I am going wrong. Whether I have to do some changes in IIS/Code/it's works like this only. I want a static URL which should not change even after re-publishing it to IIS.

Global.asax.cs

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
   {
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           RegisterRoutes();
        }

    private void RegisterRoutes()
    {
        // Edit the base address of Service1 by replacing the "Service1" string below
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(ACTServices)));
    }
}
```

Service Contract:

```
 namespace ACT
{


     [ServiceContract]
  [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode =  AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class ACTServices
{


 [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "GetUserData", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [FaultContract(typeof(ExceptionHandler))]
    public List<UserData> GetUser(UserSearchCode searchcode)
    {
        try
        {

            return objRetrieveData.GetUserfromACT(searchcode.firstName, searchcode.lastName);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ExceptionHandler eH = new ExceptionHandler();
            eH.status = "Error";
            eH.message = e.Message;
            throw new WebFaultException<ExceptionHandler>(eH, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
        //return new List<UserData>();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: "(S(2wpucy0oasurckuompimgqdo))" is the session identity added to url. So to remove it from the url you should disable session store or move it to cookies.

Comment: @IvanZub Can you tell me what should be the best option to do that? Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: I believe you could just add the following to your configuration file:
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="Off" />
  </system.web>

Comment: @IvanZub Thanks in tons.. your suggestion has worked.

Comment: you're welcome. I created the answer based on my comments, so you can now mark that question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"(S(2wpucy0oasurckuompimgqdo))" is the session identity added to url. So to remove it from the url you should just disable the session store or move it to cookies. I.e. to disable session state you can add the following to your configuration file:

```
<system.web> 
    <sessionState mode="Off" /> 
</system.web>
```

For more info please refer to the following articles on MSDN - [ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx), [Session-State Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178586(v=vs.100).aspx)